# how to move my link to the right of my submit button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the relevant code in my view:

```
<%= form_for CustomerEmail.new, :html => {:class => "js-ajax-submit js-customer-email-form invisible", :rel => {:reload => true}.to_json} do |c| -%>
  <%= c.label :email, 'Email' %>
  <%= c.text_field :email %>
  <%= c.submit "Submit", :class => "small-button" %>
  <a href="#" class='js-close-popup'>Cancel</a>
<% end -%>
```

currently the "Cancel" link is being placed to the right of the text-box labeled "Email". I need to move it to the right of the submit button.

I've tried all the html tags I know: div, span, td, tr, li. None of those got me where I needed to get.
I've also tried some css: `style='float: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px'`

no luck....

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the `text-align` property for your containing element set to `right`, would you?

Comment: By default the Cancel link should appear to the right of the Submit button. You must have some other CSS in the mix that is causing the issue. It is probably because of some floating rules.

Comment: You need to include all the relevant CSS along with your code, otherwise we would have to guess at what the problem might be and that's just not fun.

Comment: A jsFiddle demonstrating exactly what @jessegavin said: http://jsfiddle.net/ArKA6/

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for CustomerEmail.new, :html => {:class => "js-ajax-submit js-customer-email-form invisible", :rel => {:reload => true}.to_json} do |c| -%>
  <%= c.label :email, 'Email' %>
  <%= c.text_field :email %>

  <div style="float: right">
    <%= c.submit "Submit", :class => "small-button", :style => "float: left;" %>
    <div style="display: block; float: left; padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px;">
      <a href="#" class='js-close-popup'>Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```